# Problems with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need these outputs:

> nunca más

and

> nunca[ADV+NEG] más[ADV+comp]

My script:

```
import re

corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] 
otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] 
más[ADV+comp+CIRC]"

for etq in corpus:
    regex = ".*\[ADV\+NEG\+.*\]"
    results = re.findall(regex, corpus)
    print(results)
```

My results:

> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []
>
> []

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you know these are the patterns you're looking for? `"nunca más"` and `"nunca\[ADV\+NEG\] más\[ADV\+comp\]"` would give you what you want, although I doubt this is the regex you're expecting...

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your expected outputs as it is not clear.

Comment: By the way, `for etq in corpus:` will give you the characters one by one, as `corpus` is a string. You're not going to find a lot of matches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird.

It should match the entire string and return the entire string the number of characters in the string `corpus`.

Regex `.*\[ADV\+NEG\+.*\]` matches the whole `corpus`.

is this what you are looking for?

```
import re

corpus = "Me[Unknown] temo[Unknown] que[Unknown] buscare[Unknown] otras[Unknown] opciones[Unknown] esta[Unknown] nunca[ADV+NEG+CIRC] más[ADV+comp+CIRC]"
result1 = re.findall(r"(\w+)\[ADV\+.*?\]", corpus)
result2 = re.findall(r"(\w+\[ADV\+.*?)\+.*?\]", corpus)
print(" ".join(result1))
print(" ".join([x + "]" for x in result2]))
```